# How to know balance in Ledger Nano S?

Tags: wallet, api, balance, ledger-hardware-wallet, hardware-wallet

Ledger wallets have a **single static address** where to send BTC to, but when looking at the details of the transactions, it is always recorded as **different receiving addresses**. Looking up the static address on [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) (the address you send BTC to) will always show a total of `0 BTC`.

- Is there a way to know the total balance of a Ledger wallet from the
  static address?
- Is there another way to know the total balance
  without actually plugging in the Ledger device?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a receiving address?

Comment: I'm perplexed by "single static address where to send BTC", as [Ledger says](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165329-How-to-transfer-Bitcoins-to-my-Nano-S-Where-can-I-find-my-Bitcoin-address-), "your Ledger wallet generates a new address each time you want to receive a payment".

Comment: There is not a single static address.  The confusion may be that until the "current" receive address has been used to receive funds, the chrome app shows the same address every time.  Once that address has received funds, the chrome app will show a new receive address.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a blockexplorer e.g. `https://blockchain.info/xpub/${xpub}` (replace `${xpub}` with that string beginning with "xpub") to look up the balance on the web or use a wallet like e.g. [mycelium](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet).

You can look up this key as well as the private one with e.g. https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/ – **use a copy offline for your actual backup phrase**

Have a look in [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/ed96b6bea537048c97358e813bf4daea445d43d0/bip-0032.mediawiki) and 43 to learn about xpub and xprv for HD wallets (and later on BIP 39, 44 and 49).

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Sentinel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samourai.sentinel) and scan the XPUB key from the ledger's chrome wallet.

Or, if you feel paranoid, or want to change something, build the app from source:  https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/sentinel-android